# Breaking the dependency on Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, domain-driven-design

I have, what I think is a very well structured project, finally. After reading Fowler's onion architecture, learning Ninject for IOC/DI and tweaking my Psuedo repository classes, I am using EF 4.1 so DbSet and DbContext supply the repository for the most part; I am now faced with the irritating dependency on Entity Framework when wanting to "Include" other Entities / Related Entities in my repository.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to break this dependency?
For example, I have a service layer that makes calls to Repository As soon as I decide to use .Include I am bound to the fat and heavy Entity Framework... Should I go with .Join or can EF be abstracted in some way?

Comment: Just in case you haven't seen this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456853.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Julie Lerman has a post on her blog where she shows an Include extension method on `IQueryable<T>`, which allows you to use Include in your code and not break your unit tests:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
  public static IQueryable<TSource> Include<TSource>
    (this IQueryable<TSource> source, string path)
  {
    var objectQuery = source as ObjectQuery<TSource>;
    if (objectQuery != null)
    {
      return objectQuery.Include(path);
    }
    return source;
  }
}
```

See her full blog post here:
[Agile Entity Framework 4 Repository Part 5: IObjectSet and Include](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/agile-entity-framework-4-repository-part-5-iobjectset/)

Comment: Ugh, more conversion from ObjectContext to DbContext :)

Comment: Oops, I had originally thought it was an extension method against `IObjectSet<T>` and thought I'd have to put in a disclaimer since you're using a code-first model. When I saw it was `IQueryable<T>` I got excited and pasted it without looking at the method body!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbextensions(v=vs.103).aspx#Y138 It looks like some level of abstraction could be possible but a bunch of work.